# PHP/Drupal 7 error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL in (C\......)

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm building a custom node which outputs 3 sets of images, all of which will change according to a parameter passed to the mooFoo() function. however I'm getting the "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL" error and its not very descriptive, could anyone maybe give me a nod as to where I could have went wrong, I've had a scan through google without finding anything mega helpful. my code is below...

```
<?php

$rooPath = 'http://localhost/';

//path from application root
$relPath = 'trl/sites/default/files/';

$labTrl = 'TRL';
$dClass = 'ovinline';

//DEV
$imgPathRed = 'redNodePng6160.png';
$imgPathAmb = 'amberNodePng6160.png';
$imgPathGre = 'greenNodePng6160.png';

function mooFoo($img){

$img2 = $img;

switch($img2){
case 1:
      $fullPath = global $rooPath . global $relPath . global $imgPathRed;
      break;
case 2:
      $fullPath = global $rooPath . global $relPath . global $imgPathAmber;
      break;
case 3:
      $fullPath = global $rooPath . global $relPath . global $imgPathGreen;
      break;    
 }
return $fullPath;
}

?>

    <div class="<?php echo $dClass?>">
        <div class="field-label"><?php echo $labTrl?> 1:&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="field-items">
                <div class="field-item even">
                    <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="<?php echo mooFoo(2)?>" width="61" height="60" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Off top of my head I may not be able to print to screen from the way I've called mooFoo() in the html however I dont think thats where its borking so I'm assuming its to do with the way I'm trying to use the globals but I cant get right to the nuts and bolts of it...If anyone can help me out at all I'd greatly appreciate it.

Many thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your global stuff like:

```
function mooFoo($img){
  global $rooPath, $relPath, $imgPathAmber, $imgPathGreen, $imgPathRed;
 // ... more stuff here ...
 $fullPath = $rooPath . $relPath .$imgPathGreen;
 // ... more stuff here ...
}
```

You can't use the [global keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) like you're using it there.